# kube-proxy won't start in Minikube because of permission denied issue with /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kernel, arch-linux

After updating Arch Linux (sudo pacman -Syu) and restarting the system, Minikube fails to start because of kube-proxy. The logs show it was trying to modify `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max` but it ran into a permission denied issue.

I tried to run `sudo chmod 777 /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max` but the system didn't allow me. I also removed `~/.minikube` and started again, but it still refused to work. Same issue when starting `kind`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system

NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-2hkpd             0/1     Running   0          22s
etcd-minikube                      0/1     Running   0          30s
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          30s
kube-controller-manager-minikube   0/1     Running   0          30s
kube-proxy-qhhx9                   0/1     Error     2          22s
kube-scheduler-minikube            0/1     Running   0          30s
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          35s
```

```
kubectl logs kube-proxy-qhhx9 -n kube-system

I0511 04:47:08.189373       1 node.go:172] Successfully retrieved node IP: 192.168.49.2
I0511 04:47:08.189422       1 server_others.go:142] kube-proxy node IP is an IPv4 address (192.168.49.2), assume IPv4 operation
W0511 04:47:08.207109       1 server_others.go:578] Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy
I0511 04:47:08.207314       1 server_others.go:185] Using iptables Proxier.
I0511 04:47:08.208192       1 server.go:650] Version: v1.20.2
I0511 04:47:08.209006       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 131072
F0511 04:47:08.209060       1 server.go:495] open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: permission denied
```

Kernel version

```
$ uname -r
5.12.2-arch1-1
```

```
$ iptables --version
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy)
```

Comment: Hello @RedGiant. How exactly did you try to start the Minikube again? Could you please provide the steps you followed?

Comment: I just use `minikube start`. It happens every time I reboot my desktop. When I posted this thread a few days ago the problem was gone an hour without doing anything on my side. Today I rebooted the desktop and it happened again.

Comment: According to the issue https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11418 this will be fixed with minikube [v1.21.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/milestone/40) (due date is June 4)

Comment: I can confirm upgrading to v1.21.0 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 9):

change `maxPerCore` to 0 in `configMap` of `kube-proxy` to leave the limit as-is and ignore conntrack-min

Comment: Thank you, this feels like a a good solution to have on hand - just changing the ephemeral thing instead of the live host system!

Comment: For anyone else wanting to know how to change this value, the command is `kubectl edit configmap kube-proxy --namespace=kube-system`

Answer (score 4):

Getting the same issue although using kind. FWIW it helps downgrading the kernel to 5.11.

Comment: It happens every time I restart my desktop. Then after about an hour it resolves itself.

Comment: Found a related thread: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2240. Temporary fix is `sudo sysctl net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max=131072` before starting Minikube

Comment: @RedGiant That worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

There's a known bug in `kind` (see [issue #2240](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2240)), caused by a change in version 5.12.2 of the kernel to make nf_conntrack_max read-only in non-init network namespaces (more info in [the relevant commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/671c54ea8c7ff47bd88444f3fffb65bf9799ce43))

A workaround was applied in `kind` ([PR](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/pull/2241)), so as other answers have mentioned, upgrading `kind` should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading to kind `v0.11.1` solves this issue.

```
$ kind version
kind v0.11.1 go1.16.4 linux/amd64
$ uname -r
5.4.0-80-generic
```